# Handle primary key - foreign key tables insertion?

Tags: database, foreign-keys, relational-database, primary-key

Suppose I have two tables (primary key -> foreign key) where one record in primary key table corresponds to many record in foreign key, so if I want to make insert page (using ASP.NET for instance) for both primary key table and foreign key table, how can I get the primary key value to insert it into the foreign key table? 
(usually I took the max(of PK) but I am curious to find better solution)

Comment: Depends on the database system being used. But `MAX()` is usually a bad idea because it requires exclusive access to the table between the `INSERT` and the `SELECT` (achieved either by a serialized transaction or just crossing your fingers and hoping)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using SQL Server, since you mention the use of ASP.NET. Using Max(PK) is not a good idea in a multi-user system because eventually you will end up getting an incorrect primary key value. There are also resource issues to consider. In general, this approach should be avoided.

There are several ways you can accomplish what you want to do. One way is to do your inserts via stored procedures. The stored procedure for creating the primary key row would return the Id value of the new row, which then can be used for inserting your foreign key rows. But don't use Max(PK Value). Use the [SCOPE_IDENTITY()](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/) value. This assumes you are using an Identity type for your PK values. You don't state what you are actually using.

Comment: And if he is using MySQL, it would be LAST_INSERT_ID() instead of SCOPE_IDENTITY()